# SQL query is taking 25 seconds in ASP.NET to load page

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I boost the speed of page load to get data as early possible?

```
select B.bdregno, B.srno, B.bdbillno, B.bdfees as bdfees, B.bdqty as bdqty,
       B.bdrcode as bdrcode, B.bdtno as bdtno, B.bdvdate as bdvdate, T.TNAME as TNAME 
from dbo.[test] T full outer join 
     dbo.[billdet] B 
     on T.TCODE = B.bdtcode 
where" + qr + " bdregno='" + hdfregno.Value + "' 
order by bdvdate asc, srno
```

The query runs quickly in SQL Server, but in an ASP.NET application it takes approx 25 seconds to load the page.

Comment: Please tag the programming language that being used to load the page.

Comment: Step through your code and make sure, that it is indeed the execution of a simple select statement, which is causing the delay. If it works fine in SSMS, than there is no reason, why it would behave otherwise, while being executed from an application

Comment: What is the amount of data that is being transferred?

Comment: A full outer join is seldomly used. Are you sure that is what you need?

Comment: You should avoid to build your query using string concatenation. Use query parameters or Linq.

Comment: Have you tried to insert some index ? there sometimes are a very important resources because they create an order into the db and can you help to improve the prestation of your query based on the tables with index
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp
If you have the index try to understand how you can optimizing the query.
Hovewer in asp a good practice is using the ORM linq.
this is the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq

Comment: There are various different `SET` statements (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that can impact the way your query performs. If the query you're executing in SQL Server (presumably via SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio) is **exactly** the same, character for character, to the one being constructed and run in your ASP.NET application, this may be a route to investigate

Comment: record is above than 1 lac and i tried view but it takes sometime 22 sec to 27 sec and about index i got that index is not possible and even i don't know how to use index on join query

Answer (score 2):

First, I doubt you really want a full outer join.  I'm guessing a `left join` is sufficient:

```
select B.bdregno, B.srno, B.bdbillno, B.bdfees, B.bdqt,
       B.bdrcode, B.bdtno, B.bdvdate, T.TNAME 
from dbo.[billdet] B left join
     dbo.[test] T 
     on T.TCODE = B.bdtcode 
where b.bdregno = ?  --'" + hdfregno.Value + "' 
order by b.bdvdate asc, srno
```

For this query, you want indexes on `billdet(bdregno, bdtcode)`.  The engine will still need to do the wort.

Note that you should be passing the value in as a *parameter* and not munging the query string.

Comment: thank u for ans i used it but now it takes 15 to 18 sec

Comment: That is really interesting.  If the `full join` version works faster, then I suspect you have a problem with the table statistics.  You need to dive into the execution plans to see what the difference is between the `full` and `left` join versions.